# How can I pass a Craft Field into a JavaScript function?

Tags: templating

I have a chart generated in script.

```
{
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882,
    "color": "#FF6600"
},
```

This is what I want to do (and I know this is not correct).

```
{
    "country": "{{ entry.country }}",
    "visits": {{ entry.visits }},
    "color": "#FF6600"
},
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is the JavaScript inline in your template file? e.g. using `{% includeJs %}` or even just a `<script>` tag? If so you should be able to do it as you suggested by outputting Craft variables directly into the JavaScript within your template.

If the function is in an external script, you could call a function from within your template, something along these lines:

```
{% includeJsFile "/path/to/myfile.js" %}
{% set myJs %}
   myFunction('{{entry.country}}','{{entry.visits}}');
{% endset %}   
{% includeJs myJs %}
```

And then in your JS file you can have something like

```
function myfunction(country, visits){
   //do something
}
```

Comment: Another tip: you can use the `json_encode` filter within the `includeJs` tags to pass a Twig array to the JS like so: `{% includejs %}myFunction({{ myArray|json_encode|raw }});{% endincludejs %}`

Comment: useful tip @carlcs, i didnt know that :)