# Pass Craft field object to JavaScript function

Tags: includejs

I need to pass an entire Craft object into a JavaScript function. I followed the instructions in this [post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/17136/6512), however this only covers passing in a string.

```
{% includeJsFile "/js/homepage.js" %}
{% set myJs %}
   playlistData('{{myObject}}');
{% endset %}   
{% includeJs myJs %}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to break it up into individual values before you can pass it through to JS...

```
{% includeJsFile "/js/homepage.js" %}
{% set myJs %}
   playlistData({
      field1: '{{ myObject.field1 }}',
      field2: '{{ myObject.field2 }}',
      field3: '{{ myObject.field3 }}'
   });
{% endset %}   
{% includeJs myJs %}
```